# How to get access to the metaproperties of a file (aspecially a mp3 file) with vba

Tags: excel, metadata, vba

I'm creating an excel-sheets that reads the tags from the MP3-files situated in a folder. Yet the time apparently is or calculated from data inside the MetaProperties of a file or is inside those data. When I use the Property MetaProperties VBA always provokes an error, even in using a copy of the example in adapting the appropiate data. Thanx in advance for your solution.

Comment: This yields several potential results: http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=read+mp3+vba&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176591.aspx

You didn't say what metadata you want, but this method offers a lot of information.

Answer (score 0):

MP3's do not use MetaProperties at all. They actually use the last 256 bytes of the file to store album, track, etc information (the ID3 tag).

See here http://id3.org/id3v2.4.0-structure for more information.